# pm2 list not showing restart, user and uptime columns

Tags: node.js, pm2

[image]

Not only are most columns missings from pm2 console, but the process (0) running on node is not rendering my web pages even though its running and listening on a specified port.

No firewall issues and i am able to ping the port on the server with a reply.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/393834/how-to-configure-putty-to-display-these-characters) might help with the font issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because your terminal window is small. `pm2 list` , `pm2 ps` , `pm2 status`, etc won't show all columns in small width windows.

[image: sm]

and with enough room

[image: lg]

Comment: When increasing the width of window, i see more columns now but the restart column is still a question mark.

Comment: @MikeG the restart column shows how many times your process has been restarted by `pm2` itself. if you haven't set a restart strategy for your processes it won't show it at all

Comment: I restarted multiple times and the restart column still has a question mark.

Comment: as I mentioned, that's for restarts by `pm2` not manual restarts

Comment: The column has a question mark mostly likely because your terminal can't render that symbol.

Comment: Is it possible to get the small list even when my window is wide? My window is wide enough for pm2 to think to print the full table but it's not wide enough to actually display it, so the text positions get messed up

Comment: These UI changes are highly unintuitive, particularly when we only run these commands in high-pressure situations. I had lots of window space, but the extra columns didn't show. Why not just show the text in the column heading?